# How to copy values from a datatable column into a datagridview column in windows forms in c# without iterating every single row?

Tags: c#, datatable, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I have more than 9000 rows and 18 columns in my datagridview. I have to read the columns from an external datatable. If I find a match between column names, I have to copy all values from the datatable column into the datagridview column. My problem is, I cannot iterate over these rows for 18 times for more than 9000 rows and write for every iteration the value in the datagridview cell because it is too slow. Is there any valid alternative?

I add some code below so that you can understand better my question. Here I'm iterating the columns first, then the rows. Sorry for the indentation but I'm having problems in copy paste code on StackOverflow.

dgvMappatura is my dataGridView, dtExcel is my DataTable

```
foreach (DataColumn col in dtExcel.Columns)
                                            {
                                                
                                                if (col.ColumnName.Equals(nome_colonna_origine))
                                                {
                                                    
                                                    foreach (DataRow drExcel in dtExcel.Rows)
                                                    {
                                                        
                                                        
                                                        
                                                        // some code to add values to datagridview from the datatable column
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
```

Comment: If the grid is bound to `DataTable` then deal with the `DataTable` to manipulate the data and the grid will reflect the changes. Some more details and code please to understand the context.

Answer (score 0):

See if following is faster :

```
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.AsEnumerable())
            {
                var matches = row.ItemArray.Select((x, i) => new { name = x.ToString(), index = i }).GroupBy(x => x.name).Where(x => x.Count() > 1).ToArray(); 
            }
```